# how to get the position of nth occurrence of a string in a file

Tags: sed

I have an xml file which contains data in a single line where same string is repeated multiple times in it.

I am looking to identify the position of `n`th occurrence of a string in that file so that i can split single file into multiple files based on that position so that it will be easy for processing.

#### sample data in file:

```
<id = 1><\id><id = 2><\id><id = 3><\id><id = 4><\id><id = 5><\id><id = 6><\id><id = 7><\id><id = 8><\id><id = 9><\id><id = 10><\id><id = 11><\id>
```

So i want to split the file based on the id tag. for eg i want to look for position of 5th occurrence of the id tag and need to split the file into 3 files totally

#### Output:

##### file_1:

```
<id = 1><\id><id = 2><\id><id = 3><\id><id = 4><\id>
```

##### file_2:

```
<id = 5><\id><id = 6><\id><id = 7><\id><id = 8><\id>
```

##### file_3:

```
<id = 9><\id><id = 10><\id><id = 11><\id>
```

I tried splitting the one line into multiple lines with a simple sed
`sed 's/></>\n</g' $file > data.txt`
Later with a simple grep i identified the line number and started splitting based on the line number. This is working for smaller files but some file are in GB's (10-20) which is causing issues.

Could you help me if there is any easy way to get the position of the nth occurrence of a string in file so that i can split single file into multiple files based on the string position.

Comment: `an xml file` So use an xml parser. Use xmllint, xmlstarlet, use python or perl.

Comment: By all my jobs are in shell

Comment: There is a significant difference between "find the Nth occurrence of a string" and "find the nth occurrence of a tag in xml".

Comment: @lakshman The fact that your job is "in shell" does not preclude using tools like xmllint or xmlstarlet.  Indeed, the fact that you are using a shell makes it simple to use such tools.  That is the power and flexibility of the shell.

Comment: `are in shell` Weeell, sed is not in shell, it's an external program. Like any other program.

Comment: As has already been pointed out, sed is not shell. A shell would be a terrible choice for the job you're trying to do. Maybe you meant to say you only want to use the mandatory POSIX tools which are available on all Unix boxes **to be called from a shell**, e.g. sed, awk, grep, head, tail, etc. but not xmllint, xmlstarlet, python, perl, ruby, etc. that may not be present on some Unix boxes?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/<\\id>/&\n/4;P;D' file | sed -ne '1~3w file1' -e '2~3w file2' -e '3~3w file3'
```

In the first sed invocation, split each line into three following the fourth `<\id>` (BTW should this be `</id>`?).

Pipe the result to a second sed invocation.

In the second sed invocation, send the first line modulo three to `file1`, the second line modulo three to `file2` and the third line modulo three to `file3`.

Alternative using split instead of the second invocation of sed:

```
sed 's/<\\id>/&\n/4;P;D' file | split -a 1 --nume=1 -dn r/3 - file
```

Answer (score 0):

suggesting an `gawk` script (standard `awk` in most Linux machines) that can do all the splittings as well:

Parameters:

`f` : filename prefix

`m` : number of id elements in file

#### `gawk` script:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="<\\\\id>"}{a=a$0 RT}NR%m==0{print a > f NR;a=""}END{if (a)print a> f (NR-(NR%m-1)) }' f="FileName_" m=5 input.txt
```

#### Sample run on given example: `f=file_` `m=4`

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="<\\\\id>"}{a=a$0 RT}NR%m==0{print a > f NR;a=""}END{if (a)print a> f (NR-(NR%m-1)) }' f="file_" m=4 input.xml
```

##### `file_1`

```
<id = 1><\id><id = 2><\id><id = 3><\id><id = 4><\id>
```

##### `file_5`

```
<id = 5><\id><id = 6><\id><id = 7><\id><id = 8><\id>
```

##### `file_9`

```
<id = 9><\id><id = 10><\id><id = 11><\id>
```

#### `gawk` script explanation

```
BEGIN{RS="<\\\\id>"}    # set awk record seperator to <\id>
{output = output $0 RT} # accumulate each record in output variable
(NR % chunkSize) == 0 { # when read chunkSize of records
  # save output variable into file. named: filePrefix appended with record cout
  print output > filePrefix NR; 
  output = "";          # reset output variable
}
END { # after processing the last record
  if (output) { # there is existing output
    lastChunk = NR-((NR % chunkSize) - 1); # compute the file begin ID
    print output > filePrefix lastChunk; # write output to last file
  }
}
```

Comment: You should mention that awk script requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT and no parens on the right side of output redirection and arbitrary numbers of open files. You'd have completely different results with a POSIX awk.